# Oracle function doesn't recognize the input from a column of a table

Tags: sql, oracle, function, plsql

We have pre-built function which I'm using in one of my oracle PLSQL Block to get the output of the function. I'm passing a column of a field as input to the function, but I'm getting the output of the function as 0, but if I pass hard coded value to test the function I get the desired value for the same function.
Is there an issue how I pass input to the function? I saw a very similar working code in a forum based on which I developed this PLSQL block

```
DECLARE  
EXTRACT_DT_IN DATE := TO_DATE('07-JUL-17','DD-MON-RR'); 
BEGIN
insert into OPS.temp_table 
Select POT.Order_no,
OPS.function_Order_Total(mvq.quoted_order_no) 
FROM ORDER POT, mv_quoted mvq where POT.Order_no = mvq.quoted_order_no;
```

END;

I get the o/P for the above as

```
 12345 0
 23456 0
```

etc

But when I pass hard coded value to test the function as below I get the correct value

```
Select POT.Order_no,
OPS.function_Order_Total('12345') 
FROM ORDER POT, mv_quoted mvq where POT.Order_no='12345'
```

I get O/P as

```
12345 14563.23
23456 12564.76
```

etc

Your help is very appreciated and thanks in advance

Comment: I would recommend rewriting with the standard join syntax and alias your tables and columns properly and you will probably figure out your issue. Probably multiple quotes where you are expecting one.

Comment: post the code of OPS.function_Order_Total

Comment: Is it significant that you're passing ina string not a number to the function in your direct call? Whar data types are the two columns? What happens if you runthe query part of the insert directly, and if you change the columnyou pass in?

Comment: Hmm dnt think the issue is with quotes because I created a materialized view to store the field with quotes and I'm able to see the quotes in the MV. Let me try a trim on the fields, but do u think this way of triggering a function is correct? I don't want to be traveling in wrong direction before trying out different things in the present code. Anyways thanks so much for ur suggestion.

Comment: @AlexPoole let me try that and let u know. Yes I significantly use string in direct calls. I will have to confirm the string type in original function , let me check that. Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: The quotes just suggest - perhaps incorrectly - that there could be implicit conversions going on. Depends what the actual data types are, and what the function expects, and is doing. You also still haven't said what output you get from the query you use for the insert - does that get zeros, or something else? Can you also verify there isn't a trigger on `temp_table` overriding the value you're getting from the function?

Comment: @AlexPoole Confirm that when I execute with hard coded value in query it inserts exact value. Also the field types match. I will have to try to use trim on the field used in function. I have created a materialized view with order column with quotes so that I can use that in my PLsql.

Comment: Why not just run it through the debugger and watch where it departs from expectation? Otherwise we are guessing.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson thanks William. I tried debugging but not sure how to do it in SQL Developer, plz provide pointer if you can. Also today I found the issue and fixed it. See general comment on this question

Comment: Thanks every one for r thoughts and suggestion. The issue was with quotes. When I try hard coded value in query, function needs the input to be in quotes, but if I use the column name as it is as an input to the function it doesn't have to be in quotes. Just mentioning the field name without quotes will work fine. Not sure why , but it worked. Thanks everyone. If anyone knows why it worked even without quotes plz comment here.

Comment: [SQL Developer - how to start the debugger](http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2014/02/how-to-start-the-plsql-debugger)

Comment: I bet that select `count(*) from  mv_quoted where quoted_order_no = '12345';` would return 0 and that should explain this behavior of the function `OPS.function_Order_Total`.